# SPGridView sorting then grouping problem

Tags: spgridview

I'm using SPGridview with LinqDataSource and Generic List.
I'm having problem when try to do grouping after sorting. Please refer to the screen shot below.

[image]

Its grouping in the order of the previous states even though I will order first my data before binding.
It's work fine if I don't do any sorting first before grouping.
The grouping value is based from a DropDownList.

Appreciate any helps.
Thanks In Advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yeah this is an annoying issue with the SPGridView. It expects the data to be sorted by the column you are grouping by.

```
// _grid is an SPGridView
_grid.Sort("Category", SortDirection.Ascending);
```

However, only your Grouping will be sorted and not the rows within each group. What you really need to do is NOT use `SPGridView.Sort`. Make sure the data is **pre-sorted**.

For example, here is how I do it using a `DataView`.

```
// view is a DataView in this example
// first column has to be the column you are grouping by
view.Sort = string.Format("{0}, {1}", "Category", "ReferenceNumber");
```

Looks like for the `LinqDataSource`, you would use [Sort By and Then By](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb547057.aspx).

Comment: Thanks, I solved it by using OrderBy("category").ThenBy("Title"). And the trick is that if the dropdownlist selected index > 0 then i will disable AutoSort of the LinqDataSource. Thanks again.

Comment: I am facing the same issue . Can you please post the exact code .